# Expanding template parameter pack to declare class members

Tags: c++

First, I have a template class:

```
template <typename T>
class Component;
```

Then I would like to create a class that can hold an arbitrary set of `Component<T>`'s as members, e.g. for `N=2`:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Aggregate
{
private:
  Component<T>* m_comp1;
  Component<U>* m_comp2;
};
```

At first glance, this looks like using variadic template would be a natural application.

```
template <typename... Comps>
class Aggregate
{
// what should go here for me to get Component<Comp1>, Component<Comp2>, ...?
};
```

However, I am unable to write the code that would essentially allow me to go from `T, U, ... -> C<T>, C<U>, ...`. Currently, I have this achieved by creating a partial specialization for each `N=1,2,3,4,...` case, but this yields a lot of duplicated boilerplate code (and I would like to avoid having to write the `Aggregate` class to take in the template parameters directly as `<Comp<T>,Comp<U>,...>`). Is there a way to achieve the above? Thank you for any feedback/help in advance.

Comment: Derive `Aggregate<U, T>` from `Aggregate<U>` and add the additional member. You can do so recursively.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You're describing a `tuple`

Comment: `std::tuple` or `boost::tuple` is *exactly* the right code to look at to get inspiration, yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a tuple:

```
template <typename... Comps>
using Aggregate = std::tuple<Component<Comps>*...>;
```

Comment: Well, when you don't know what `tuple` is, there's not much you can do besides asking a human

Comment: that is not a critism, it is just that I hope my answer is relevant... If that's the case, that's good news :)

Comment: This answer indeed was the relevant one. I had known that std::tuple existed, but was not at all observant enough to have read the documentation or examples such that anything like your expression was possible. With the combination of your answer + lambda + fold expression, I have been able to write the full implementation of the class I wanted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple solution. Use `std::tuple`. Otherwise you'd need to reimplement it yourself, which is not trivial.